# How can I compare the webtable data with a csv file using protractor and node js?

Tags: node.js, csv, protractor

How can I compare the webtable data with a csv file using protractor and node js?
The task I'm trying to accomplish here is to able to download a webtable data and then compare the data is what I downloaded by comparing with the csv with the webtable cell by cell. I'm using protractor (quite new to it) with node js (obviously) (also very novice at it).

Comment: please share what you have tried

Comment: read the webtable and csv into two arrays, use assertion library to compare the two arrays in one time.